# How do I change the text size and color within tabs when using SlidingTabLayout in Android?

Tags: android

So the effect will be each individual tab will be a little larger in addition to the text color change.  I've tried using the setCustomTabView() but it only applies to the first tab and the rest of my tabs are unrendered.

Answer (score 0):

So here is an example using setCustomTabView():

In your layout you have the ViewPager and the SlidingTabLayout :

```
<com.yourProject.SlidingTabLayout  <--- IMPORT latest from Google[*see link]
        android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager android:id="@+id/viewPager"
                                     android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/text_size_medium"
                                       android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                       android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

- https://github.com/google/iosched/blob/master/android/src/main/java/com/google/samples/apps/iosched/ui/widget/SlidingTabLayout.java and also here you will find SlidingTabStrip, which is also needed.

Then in your fragment or activity, set the custom view for the the sliding tab like this:

```
 viewPager = (ViewPager) rootView.findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
 mSlidingTabLayout = (SlidingTabLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.sliding_tabs);
    mSlidingTabLayout.setSelectedIndicatorColors(getResources().getColor(R.color.accent));
    mSlidingTabLayout.setCustomTabView(R.layout.sliding_tab_layout_custom, R.id.item);
    mSlidingTabLayout.setDistributeEvenly(false);
    mSlidingTabLayout.setViewPager(viewPager);
```

With your custom layout for the tab being:

../layout/sliding_tab_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="horizontal">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="@dimen/text_size_small"
        android:textColor="@color/primary"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_medium"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

The example was tested, so it should work. Hope it helps :)